# C++ precompiled-headers huge in size

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers

I have 2 questions about c++ precompiled-headers feature.

1.What actually is happening when you make a .gch file (using GCC), what it contains ?

2.Why those files are so huge in size , but the final executable is so small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you precompile a header, it all begins like an usual compilation:

- The preprocessor is run, including any dependent headers and performing macro substitution
- The resulting source code is hander over to the compiler, which parses it and validates the syntax
- Then the compiler produces the AST, the data structure which encodes the *semantics* of the code

Usually, this is done on `.cpp` files, and goes on afterwards to actually compile the AST and generate executable code. However, a header precompilation stops there, and the compiler dumps the AST inside the `.gch` file.

On further uses of this precompiled header, the compiler can then directly load the AST back from file and pick it up from there, skipping the costly processing listed above.

The `.gch` file is huge, because it contains a lot of information that was implicit in the original header. But it has no relation to the size of the final executable -- compiling with and without precompiled headers should produce the exact same result.